# Angular change css of different directive

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a real problem to change some simple css with Angular and css.

I have the code:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" ng-class="stepOne">1</div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" ng-class="stepTwo">2</div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" ng-class="stepTree">3</div>
</div>

<div class="well col-lg-12">
    <applystepone ng-if="step.one"></applystepone>  <!-- this is my directive -->
    <applysteptwo ng-if="step.two"></applysteptwo>
    <applysteptree ng-if="step.tree"></applysteptree> 

</div>
```

In the directive : applystepone i have a button. If I click on the button i want the css of the progress bar change for `ng-class="stepOne"`

The button in the directive :

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="steptwo(); stepOne='valide-step'">Next step</a> 
</div>
```

And the directive :

```
app.directive('applystepone', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/apply-step-one.html'
    };
});
```

If i click on the button, nothing append to the

```
ng-class="stepOne"
```

If i place in the `apply-step-one.html`

```
<p ng-class="stepOne">Test </p>
```

The css works, so the button works fine. I suppose it's because my ng-click is in the directive and not the `ng-class="stepOne"`.

Comment: Halfway through writing my answer, I've realized I have no idea what exactly is the problem (but still gave you solutions for two problems). Can you tell exactly what you want to achieve and what's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure I understood the whole thing, but here it goes.

I think you should consider modifying your CSS (which you haven't shown, btw) and the code slightly:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" ng-class="{active: step.one}">1</div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" ng-class="{active: step.two}">2</div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" ng-class="{active: step.three}">3</div>
</div>
```

This would trigger the `active` class on your progress bar based on the step in scope.

Then, instead of

```
<p ng-class="stepOne">Test </p>
```

you should probably use something more generic like:

```
<p class="button">Test </p>
```

and modify the CSS to trigger it, for example:

```
.well p.button {
    color: green;
}
```

---

And if you just want to modify the class of the button, it's simple:

```
<p ng-class="{'stepOne': step.one, 'stepTwo': step.two, 'stepThree': step.three}">Test </p>
```

It's similar to what I described above, for the progress bar divs.

Comment: The solution with `ng-class="{active: step.one}"` is really good. More proper i think, my button stay clean without `stepOne='valide-step'`. Also i had `ng-hide="step.two"` to `<applystepone></applystepone> ` to hide the element if we pass the second step...

Comment: Yeah, you should let CSS handle the styling, and angular just to switch between elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="steptwo(); $parent.stepOne='valide-step'">Next step</a>
```

$parent will retrieve the parent scope from inside your directive.